# Renaming elements of a nested list with dynamic number of items in R

Tags: r

I just want to preface this question by saying I am a novice in both R (and any coding in general) and stack overflow. I apologize if I am unclear in relaying my question or haven't provided enough details.

I've set up my R script currently to import all the csv files contained in a directory and read them all into a single list of lists with the following:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

So if I had 4 csv files in the working directory, it would create a list with 4 nested lists within it. These nested lists are named as a number in the order they are read (1 to 4 for 4 csv files imported), but I want them to retain the original names of the csv files. Is there a way to change the way I am reading the csv files into R so that they retain the original file names of the csv?

I am able to change the names of the list elements manually with the following, since temp holds all the csv file names:

```
names(myfiles) <- c(temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4])
```

However, this would only work given that I only have 4 csv files within the directory. I was not able to figure out how to write this code so that it works for a dynamic number of csv files.

I have tried to make a for loop along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  names(myfiles) <- c(temp[i])
}
```

but I wasn't able to figure out how to make the vector c() encapsulate a dynamic number of list elements. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you need `names(myfiles) <- temp`

Comment: Ah, it's as simple as that, I guess I was over-complicating things. Thank you!

Comment: `sapply(temp, read.csv, simplify = FALSE)` works on the first call instead of a double-call of `lapply` and `names`.